# Save state of select menu with EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible with EmberJS to retrieve the state of a select box (AKA drop down menu), given a route?

Here would be my user story which is fairly simple:

A User wants to filter a list of items by the means of a select menu located on the top. 
Upon selecting an item, the list get automatically filtered. The state of the filter is persisted in the URL enabling the User
to retrieve a selection.

```
URL: http://example.com/#/2   -> where 2 corresponds to an item in the filter

------------------------------
| Select an item         \/  |
------------------------------

* Item 1
* Item 2
* Item 3
```

Here would be my Select view:

```
App.CitySelectView = Ember.Select.extend({
    contentBinding: "App.cityController.cities",
    optionLabelPath: "content.name",
    optionValuePath: "content.uid",
    selectionBinding: "App.cityController.selected"
});
```

The template would look like that.

```
{{view App.StateSelectView id="form-select-state" prompt="Select an item"}}
```

I would need a router but I am not sure how to write it. What I am missing for instance, is the ability to write an {action} on the Select View which should be triggered on "change".

Can you help?

Ps. I have this link in my pipeline related to routing https://gist.github.com/2728699

Comment: Since your select view is bound to the `selected` property of your controller you don't need to add event handler to that. In you cityController you could observe changes to the `selected` property and then when it changes you could call a method on your router than transitions to appropriate route, passing in the new `selected` object as the context for that route.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to handle this would be by observing the selected value in the controller, then passing the changed value to the router using the send event. In the router, you can call transitionTo to change the url and perform the filtering.

In App.CityController:

```
selectedChanged: function() {
    App.router.send('filterDropDown', this.get('selected'));
}.observes('selected')
```

In App.Router, the defined event sent to the router is called:

```
filterDropDown: function(router, context) {
    router.transitionTo('filter', context.uid);  //pass the uid as url param
}
```

Define a route and handle the filtering in the enter event:

```
filter: Em.Route.extend({
    router: '/:selected',
    enter: function(router, context) {
        // Handle filtering here, with selected uid as context.selected
    }
})
```

You may need to mess with the serialize and deserialize to get it to work for your case.